# how to use shared library in makefile c++

Tags: c++, makefile, include, shared-libraries, dynamic-library

I am very new to makefiles and I couldn't find any clear tutorials to follow regarding the libraries, therefore my questions are more about the concepts than the code.

I have two c++ files and 5 header files. I want to make a makefile that creates a dynamic (shared) library so i can use it in a test file and it is in the current directory. The shared library .so is created but is passing it in this way is the right way to be read by the program? and should header files which has no (.cc) related files be also included in the makefile and the library? lastly: should the .so file be included in the test file as `#include <mylib.so>` or is running the makefile will connect it automatically?

this is my code:

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -g
CC = g++

all: Class1.o main.o mylib.so 
    $(CC) Class1.o main.o mylib.so -o myProg

mylib.so : Class1.o.o main.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -shared -fPIC -o mylib.so Class1.o main.o

Class1.o: Class1.cc Class1.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c Class1.cc

main.o: main.cc  
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c main.cc -L. -lmylib
```

thanks in advance

Comment: For starters you need to distinguish between the files that _make up_ your library and the ones that _use_ your library. `main.o` cannot at the same time be a part of mylib (see the `mylib.so` rule) and link to it (see the `main.o` rule)

Comment: You have some misconceptions about shared libraries, which you must clear up before you try to write the makefile. In general, you cannot do anything with Make until you know how to do it *without* Make.

Comment: @Botje so the library should only have the header files and the cpp files but not the test file. If i have header files without cpp files should i also include them in the mylib.so rule? or only those related to cpp files? 
so for example ```mylib.so : Class1.o A.h B.h C.h```
    and ```$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -shared -fPIC -o mylib.so Class1.o A.h B.h C.h```

Comment: When you use the `#include` pre-processor macro to include something, what you are effectively doing is copying all the text from the included file and pasting in the place where you put the `#include`. Almost always what you include is a header file and sometimes (for very specific reasons) it could be a `cpp` file. You will never include a binary file, such as a compiled library, since it does not make sense.